# ZentriOS IDE setup error

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I am trying to install the [ZentriOS](https://docs.zentri.com/zentrios/wz/latest/sdk/user-guide/custom-sdk-installation) IDE and the following error message pops up. I'm am really not sure what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank You!!

[image: zentri ide error message]

Answer (score 0):

This may come a bit late for you, but this is an Eclipse installation issue. The ZentriOS IDE requires 64 bit java to be installed on your system.